# C++ std::thread inside class and std::vector

Tags: c++, multithreading, vector, stdthread

What is a proper way to add std::thread into class and vector?
I have a class that containing threads. I need to create threads and to save them in vector.
How to do it correctly?

```
class CIED
{
public:
    
    std::string m_IEDName;          
    std::string m_IP;               

    thread  threadConnection;
    
    CIED()
    {
        m_IEDName.empty();
        m_IP.empty();
        threadConnection = std::thread([]() {});
    }
    CIED(std::string IEDName, std::string IP)
    {
        m_IEDName = IEDName;
        m_IP = IP;
        threadConnection = std::thread([]() {});
    }

    virtual ~CIED() { };

    CIED& operator=(const CIED& from)
    {
        m_IEDName = from.m_IEDName;
        m_IP = from.m_IP;
        // what with threadConnection ???

        return *this;
    }
};
```

...

```
    vector<CIED> m_vecIED;
```

... do something

```
            for (int i = 0; i < m_vecIED.size(); ++i)
            {
                if (m_vecIED[i].m_IP == itt->second.m_IP)
                {
                    m_vecIED[i].threadConnection = thread(connectionWasLost, m_vecIED[i].m_IEDName);
                    m_vecIED[i].threadConnection.detach();
                    break;
                }
            }
```

errors are:

```
Error       use of deleted function ‘CIED::CIED(const CIED&)’       
Error       use of deleted function ‘std::thread::thread(const std::thread&)’       
Error       use of deleted function ‘CIED::CIED(const CIED&)’
```

Comment: `std::thread` is not copy-able, as the error tells you. And why did you only declare a copy-assignment operator in your class? You almost always need to have both operator and constructor

Comment: You cannot copy a thread (because then you would have two threads). Normally you would want to move them instead, which means writing a move constructor and move assignment operator for class CEID.

Comment: On an unrelated note, there's no need for `threadConnection = std::thread([]() {});` A default-initialized `std::thread` object will be perfectly fine. Also, what do you think that `m_IEDName.empty();` will do? The `empty()` function checks if the string is empty, and return a boolean result. It doesn't clear or make a string empty. Beside, you should learn about constructor initializer lists.

Comment: This code compiles ok for me